# Комментарий при отклонении правки

Tags: поддержка, предложение

Как поступать, если при отклонении правки хочешь оставить комментарий? Всегда выбирать последний пункт "Несёт вред", или же всё-таки выбирать более подходящий другой пункт, а комментарий засовывать в другое место? Кстати, в какое? Ведь позвать человека, чья правка отклонена (или ещё нет) под вопросом нельзя.

И ещё, вредит ли последний пункт тому, чья правка отклоняется, больше, чем остальные?

[Пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/140058)

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Думаю, достаточно важный вопрос. Было бы неплохо, если бы была возможность добавлять комментарий независимо от выбранного пункта. И тому, кто предложил правку будет полезно узнать с чем несогласен тот, кто отклонил.

Comment: `вредит ли последний пункт тому, чья правка отклоняется, больше` – вроде нет, в статистике различные причины отклонения правки никак не различаются между собой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, даже первая? За спам же санкции есть - неужели за правки, добавляющие спам, нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy хороший вопрос, надо бы поисследовать.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, «несёт вред» — это обобщение всех вышеуказанных причин. Этот вариант нужен как раз для случаев, когда вы отклоняете правку по какой-то конкретной причине, не описанной другими случаями.

У этого способа есть одно ограничение: автор предлагаемой правки не получит уведомления. Читают эти комментарии тоже, вероятно, не все. Если вы хотите, чтобы автор наверняка узнал о сообщении и прочитал его, лучше оставить комментарий где-нибудь под последним ответом. Если ситуация совсем катастрофическая — можно передать задачу модераторам, у них есть ещё более убедительный канал связи. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну почему же только отклонять... я иногда комментирую и правки, которые принимаю. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622270/213987): "Извинения за траслит приравниваются к согласию на правку комментария ;) Одобрил."

Поэтому выбираю обычно пункт "не содержит никаких улучшений" (или что подходит лучше по обстоятельствам), а потом начинаю комментировать под сообщением и искать способ уведомить пользователя, выдавшего правку. Последний ответ -- хорошее место ;) Главное -- не забыть потереть потом комментарий как ненужный.

Не очень удобно, но пока только такой workflow могу посоветовать из своего личного опыта.

И ещё способ.

Очень аккуратно, но могу порекомендовать использовать приём «Жми "отклонить и править" вместо "отклонить"» (он же «Жми "принять и править" вместо "принять"»): можно часть правки переделать по-своему, главное -- появляется строка "Описание" правки, где можно загнать часть объяснения.

Жирный минус у этого метода: правка сразу уходит в продакшн, не дожидаясь остальных проверяющих. Я считаю это минусом, так как лучше пять пар глаз просмотрят, а не один будет диктовать своё видение: может оказаться неправильным.

Comment: Минус второго способа в том, что тот, кто предложил правку, комментарий не увидит. А вот собственная правка без проверки - это не проблема.