# Как обсудить причины отклонения правки чужого ответа?

Tags: поддержка, правки, отклонённые-правки

В вопросе про [length и length()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842017/length-%D0%B8-length/) участником [Санаев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260992/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2) был дан ответ, который сводится к описанию механизма вычисления длины строки в Java после появления компактных строк в Java 9. Ответ был не вполне качественно оформлен и в нём была дана неверно отформатированная ссылка на сторонний сайт.

Я исправил этот ответ, полностью сохранив исходный посыл и логическое содержание ответа Санаева. Вот ссылка на мою правку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/289220 Моя правка всё ещё ожидает подтверждения, но её уже успел отклонить [Suvitruf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf), указав в качестве причины, что: "Правка не соответствует исходному содержанию сообщения". Я не согласен с этим и хотел бы это с ним обсудить. Как мне это сделать?

Дополнение: Вопрос [Комментарий при отклонении правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4714/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8) не является дубликатом моего вопроса, поскольку там речь идёт о комментариях того, кто отклоняет правку, а не того, чья правка отклонена.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Комментарий при отклонении правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4714/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Обычно такое в чате обсуждается https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--.

Лично я зачастую отклоняю такие правки, т.к. они могут исказить/поменять смысл, который закладывал автор.

Если у вас есть какие-то замечания/правки/дополнения, то возможно стоит это оформить отдельным ответом?

Comment: На самом деле я не согласен с ответом Санаева и уже опубликовал собственный ответ. Однако без всякой связи с моим несогласием ответ Санаева содержит более-менее правильное описание существующей реализации `String#length()` и поэтому я посчитал необходимым отредактировать именно это описание, хотя оно и не является настоящей причиной того, что в джавовских строках изначально решили сделать метод `length()` а не финальное публичное поле `length`, как в массивах.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку [на stackoverflow нет механизма личных сообщений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5159/213987) то можно сделать следующее.

Открываете профиль участника, который отклонил правку, ищете его ответы или вопросы и оставляете комментарий под последним его постом. Такие комментарии попадут в инбокс и когда участник появится и прочитает - тогда вы и подискутируете с ним в комментах под вопросом.

Когда такое обсуждение закончится - не забудьте предложить почистить комментарии, так как они не относятся к вопросу/ответу, под которым вы беседовали.

Другой способ - пройти в [основной чат сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). С высокой вероятностью участник, которого вы ищете будет в том чате (у нас не так много проверяющих и большинство из них есть в чате) и можно будет обсудить в рилтайм режиме, не зашумляя основной сайт.

Также, даже если проверяющий не является участником чата - всегда можно обсудить ситуацию с завсегдатаями чата, получить консультацию.